# padding-top in div set to variable

Tags: php, html, css

Here is my code:

```
return '<div style="width: 100%; height: 0; position: relative; padding-top: 56.25%">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;">
    <unitydog width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" src="'.$url.'" extraClass="'.$classes.'" fullscreen="'.$fullscreen.'"
    preview="'.$preview.'"></unitydog></div></div>';
```

I want to set the padding-top with a variable. Earlier on, I assign a value to $aspect ("56.25%" to be exact). I want the padding-top to get its value from $aspect.

I tried to replace the code with this:

```
return '<div style="width: 100%; height: 0; position: relative; padding-top: "'.$aspect.'"">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;">
    <unitydog width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" src="'.$url.'" extraClass="'.$classes.'" fullscreen="'.$fullscreen.'"
    preview="'.$preview.'"></unitydog></div></div>';
```

but it doesn't seem to work. The whole thing just disappears. How can I do this remembering that I'm in a return statement, so I can't go back and edit the .css later?

Comment: Is there any PHP error, what do you mean *disappears*?

Comment: `var_dump($aspect)` also make sure that you're using `56.25%` and not just `56.25` as that will do nothing.

Comment: I tried various things and nothing worked. Here is what I tried:

padding-top: "'.var_dump($aspect).'""
padding-top: var_dump($aspect)
padding-top: .var_dump($aspect).

BTW my $aspect it a string which is "56.25%". Should I have it as a float/double and add the % later? If so, then how?

Comment: I don't get you. Are you trying to set padding-top with a variable, or are you trying to set it to 56.25%? Secondly, what do you mean by "whole thing just disappears"? Do you mean you don't see the `div` at all?

Comment: yes, the <div> disappears

Comment: So did the first block of code work? Or was it also problematic?

Comment: I want a shortCode to include an $aspect veriable. [myShortCode aspect="56.25"] 

Later, in the thing.php I want to set the top-padding to that variable

Comment: the first block of code worked fine

Comment: Ok. I think your problem is a typo. You need to set `$aspect` to a string value `"56.25%"`, not a float value.

Comment: That's exactly what I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is a typo, particularly your first line:

```
return '<div style="width: 100%; height: 0; position: relative; padding-top: "'.$aspect.'"">
```

Look at the quotes just before `$aspect`. You are closing the style tag with `"` before you closed the string with `'`.

You probably want:

```
return '<div style="width: 100%; height: 0; position: relative; padding-top: '.$aspect.'">
```

Answer (score 2):

When you need to insert variables in a string, you need to start the strings with double-quotes and to insert a variable you can break the string with other double-quotes increase a point . and the name of a variable.

For the correct answer, the alternative to write the html with attributes in a string PHP you need consider wich the attr delimiters need to start with single-quotes,

example: `return "<div style='width:100%; ". $variable ."'></div>";`

All the properties of CSS, never have value with quotes(double and single) like this -> color: '#333333'. Only html attributes declarations have delimiters quotes. The answer above is incorrect about this.

In conclusion you might test this:

```
return "<div style='width: 100%; height: 0; position: relative; padding-top: ".$aspect."'>
    <div style='position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;'>
    <unitydog width='".$width."' height='".$height."' src='".$url."' extraClass='".$classes."' fullscreen='".$fullscreen."'
    preview='".$preview."'></unitydog></div></div>";
```

See in this case the double-quotes is only to open and close the string PHP and not modify the html.

Wait to be helpful for you. If it's useful for you please give a like :)